# Can an electron in a given band have a well-defined position?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, second-quantization

In a book I am using (*Quantum Theory of the Optical and Electronic Properties of Semiconductors,* chapter on Quantum Dots), they define separate position space creation operators for an electron and hole, $\psi_e^\dagger(\boldsymbol{r})$ and $\psi_h^\dagger(\boldsymbol{r})$. How is this possible given that, if an electron and hole had a well-defined position $\boldsymbol{r}$, there would be no distinction between their wavefunctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons and holes are characterized by more than their position. They have charge, in fact, opposite charge between one another.

Comment: Wouldn't this then imply that the matrix element between the electron and hole state is zero? The book is suggesting that they have perfect overlap, e.g. in the expression for the dipole moment.

Comment: The projection of an electron state onto a hole state _is_ zero, but some thing like the dipole operator (or in general anything sensitive to electromagnetism) would couple the hole and electron sectors of the spectrum, giving it a nonzero matrix element. In practice, $\Psi_e$, $\Psi_h$ only refer to the position space part of the state.

Comment: OK, so my misunderstanding was that the dipole operator acts only on the position part of the states in the matrix element, and that the charge parts are orthogonal so give zero, when in fact it also acts on the charge part, coupling the electron and hole states?